# My Excel formula NETWORKDAYS is giving wrong result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

when I am using `=NETWORKDAYS(DATE(YEAR(F79),MONTH(F79),DAY(F79)),TODAY())` formula, I am getting a result of 2 which is wrong where `F79 cell has value = 27-12-2023  17:46:32 and today() value is 28-12-2023`. why?

`if I do =today()-F79 result is 0`, which is correct. but network days formula gives result as 2 which is Wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, `NETWORKDAYS()` returns the number of whole working days between ***start_date*** and ***end_date***. See [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) from microsoft page.

As per above description it would be `2` as it is calculation whole working day of `27-12-2023` and `28-12-2023`.

On the other hand `=TODAY()-F79` giving you `1` because it is subtracting from current date to yesterday date which is `1`. So, those are two different type of calculation.

Comment: =TODAY()-F79 is coming as 0 not 1. but I think it is because of the time part in F79.  and the difference is less then 12 Hrs hence it might be.

also taking the above hint into account I have checked other values in the table and found that if the difference is more then 12 hrs but less then 36 Hrs the result is 1.

Thanks for the help